# Retrieve firebase data with android and sort by child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys im trying to retrieve data from firebase that only start with letter C and sort alphabetical but when i run the program it does nothing i can retrieve all Rooms with no problem. here is my code please help.

```
public class RoomsActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private Button  add_room;
    private EditText room_name;

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> list_of_rooms = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
    private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
    private String user_name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rooms);

        name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.back2);
        add_room = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_room);
        room_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.room_name_edittext);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list_of_rooms);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        add_room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put(room_name.getText().toString(),"");
                root.updateChildren(map);
            }
        });

        root.child("room_name").startAt("C").orderByKey().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

                while (i.hasNext()){
                    set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());
                }

                list_of_rooms.clear();
                list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Chat_Room.class);
                intent.putExtra("room_name",((TextView)view).getText().toString() );
                intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my database

```
private DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
```

when ii get the root all data is retrieved

```
root.orderByKey().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){
        set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());
    }

    list_of_rooms.clear();
    list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

i used [firebase docs][1] as reference but cant get it to work

Screenshot 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CpFM.jpg

Comment: Could you attach screenshots of your Firebase data?

Comment: @boonyakipitak screenshot added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc of `Java Admin` you can do something like this it should also work with `Android`

For data starting with `C`,

`dinosaursRef.orderByKey().startAt("C").endAt("C\uf8ff")`

The `\uf8ff` is after most regular characters in Unicode, so the query should matches all values that start with a `C`.

Sorry if it is not working, i didn't personally try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
root.orderByKey().startAt("C").endAt("C\uf8ff").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

it worked when adding the .endAt() here a solution if someone needs it. Thanks